# Deploying application in elastic beanstalk AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created multiple REST api's for my website on a local server(wamp) and now i am trying to move it to a online server(aws elastic beanstalk). My question is where do i build my database with the tables and rows etc just like in phpmyadmin? I figured that "upload and deploy" means upload the php file i made but when i do i get an error saying "health degraded". So what i want to do is basically move my local server to an online one with aws EB. I watched a bunch of videos and did a lot of research but can't seem to find the way to go about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is where do i build my database with the tables and rows
>   etc just like in phpmyadmin?

You can connect to the RDS instance created by beanstalk using a Database Management Client Tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), [Heidi SQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) & etc using the DNS name, created for RDS instance. However one challenge you will face is to access the RDS instance from your client machine, since its not a good practice to make the Database publicly accessible. You can create a EC2 instance (Windows or Linux with GUI) inside the same VPC, connect to it (Remote Desktop or SSH) and install the tools so that you can use the tools inside the server, to connect to the RDS instance.

> I figured that "upload and deploy" means upload the php file i made
>   but when i do i get an error saying "health degraded"

To understand the structure in code inside the Zip file, I would recommend to create a Beanstalk environment with a sample project available in Beanstalk and download the sample project artifact (Zip file) from S3 so that you can compare the project structure requirements.

If you prefer to go through the documentation, you can refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html). If nothing goes well, connect to the ElasticBeanstalk provisioned EC2 instance (Either using Remote Desktop for Windows or SSH to linux) and investigate the deployed artifacts.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my laptop has been acting up the past couple of days. But i would create an EC2 instance and download the tools(MySQL workbench) on there and build my table and rows?

Comment: @Jagr Thats one option to do. Another alternative is to setup your build environment EC2 instance inside the network and automate executing the scripts (If changes are there) upon a build.

Comment: So you mean build the instance and when i am on the Windows remote desktop download the files for the beanstalk? Sorry i am very new to this and its very confusing. Like all i want to do is take my local server and make it online

Comment: Option 1) Whats mentioned above (By creating a EC2 instance, install MySQL Workbench Tools and run the scripts manually)
Option 2) You can keep the database scripts along with source code, and automate the database scripts execution (This can be done in a build server hosted in a EC2 instance within the same VPC)

Comment: Yea i want to use Elasticbeanstalk so that would be option 2?

Comment: Yes I would prefer Option 2

Comment: To connect to the RDS instance you need like "MYSQL server " but it didn't come with my Windows AMI. And i cant even download it D: Is there a way to get help from you 1 on 1? or tutorials out there that is specific to my needs?

Comment: If you are not able to download, is it because of a networking issue? Are you able to access other websites from your windows?